# Google API -> Unable to obtain access token from JWT

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, jwt

I want to call Google API Analytics using Account service token generated from server.

I followed the guide on this [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)

This is my code for generating signed JSON Web Token:

```
    final GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(JWTSample.class.getResourceAsStream ("/account_secrets.json"))
            .createScoped(List.of(
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics",
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly")
            );
    final PrivateKey privateKey = credential.getServiceAccountPrivateKey();
    final String privateKeyId = credential.getServiceAccountPrivateKeyId();
    try {

        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256(null, (RSAPrivateKey) privateKey);
        String signedJwt = JWT.create()
                .withKeyId(privateKeyId)
                .withIssuer("test-295@symbolic-folio-268713.iam.gserviceaccount.com")
                .withAudience("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token")
                .withIssuedAt(new Date(now))
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(now + 3600 * 1000L))
                .sign(algorithm);
        System.out.println(signedJwt);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The output is a signed JWT.

When I call Oauth2 service to generate access_token from signed JWT

```
 curl -d 'grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion=<signed_JWT>' https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
```

I receive this error:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_scope",
    "error_description": "Invalid oauth scope or ID token audience provided."
}
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decode the JWT assertion claim-set with `echo "${SIGNED_JWT}" | cut -d. -f2 | base64 --decode` and you'll see that there is no `scope` attribute.

The `GoogleCredential` instance has the scopes but they're not being passed to the JWT builder.

Add the scopes with this additional method after your `JWT.create()`:

```
.withClaim("scope", credential.getServiceAccountScopesAsString())
```

Comment: Without your help I'd never made this. Thank you very much (and shame again on google documentation)